# Why can't LLDB print an IBAction's sender argument?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, lldb

I am trying to print the sender in a breakpoint inside a method. My method has this signature:

`- (IBAction)purchaseButtonTapped:(id)sender`

I type `po sender` into lldb when my program hits the breakpoint inside that method, and I'm getting this:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'sender'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Any other `p`, `po`, or `c` commands that I use work without a problem. If I `NSLog` my sender e.g. `NSLog(@"%@", sender);` it does print my `UIButton` object without a problem. Is this a bug in lldb, or did my brain turn into inanimate molten lava because of coding for hours and I can't see something obvious?

Comment: If you have the `NSLog` statement in the method, then can you `po sender` in the debugger?

Comment: yes, I can. something even more weird: I've removed the `NSLog` and now I can `po sender` too without error. is this a compiler optimization bug or something?

Answer (score 2):

In a release build, if the method doesn't use the `sender` argument, the compiler doesn't create an entry for it in the debug symbol table.  So you can't `po sender` in the debugger.  If you know how the argument is passed (in which register or where on the stack), you can print it that way.

In a debug build, you should always be able to `po sender`.

Comment: it was a debug build. it's probably a compiler/debugger bug.